# Expectation of Uniform Distribution with Sin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, uniform-distribution

> Let $X ∼ \operatorname{Unif} (a, b)$. What is $E[\sin(X)]$?

I know how to find the expectation of a uniform distribution, but I'm unsure how to find $E[\sin(x)]$.

$\int_{a}^{b}x(\frac{1}{b-a})dx$

Comment: Same way, only with $\sin(x)$ instead of $x$ in the integral.

Comment: @NormalHuman that's what I suspected, but thank you for solidifying that for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'll put Normal Hunman's answer here for the sake of completeness:

$\int_{a}^{b}\sin(x)(\frac{1}{b-a})dx$